# Hiding DOM elements during device orientation change?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, orientation

When changing the orientation on a mobile device (low-end / mid-tier) with e.g. stackoverflow opened in the browser, a noticeable white area is visible for a small period of time. See gif below.

[image: device orientation white area]

To reproduce for yourself, open [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/), or any site with a decent amount of DOM elements in Chrome. Press `f12`, press `ctrl + shift + m` (to open the device toolbar), select a device and change `Online` to e.g. `Mid-tier mobile`, then you can observe the white area, just by clicking the `rotate` button.

Of course, the root cause is the amount of DOM elements present (they don't have to be in the viewport per se). If you were to perform the same actions as described above, say, on the page of this question, the lag / white area is hard to observe.

A solution would be to hide those containers that contain a lot of DOM elements and to increase performance even further, hide those elements that fall out of the viewport (with a given safe area).

But, unfortunate, there is no such thing as `ondeviceorientationStart` and `ondeviceorientationEnd`, or a mediaquery that could be leveraged... So the question is, *is there a hook / technique to hide elements **during** the orientation change*?

**EDIT:** as suggested, the `resize` event is where we all would start. This event however, comes to late. If we continue using the stackoverflow site and were to hide all the elements, those elements would be hidden **after** the orientation change took place. Snippet:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  var els = document.querySelectorAll(".-summary"),
    i = 0,
    l = els.length;

  for (i; i < l; i++) {
    els[i].style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

Comment: What about `window.onresize`

Comment: Plus `if (window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight) portrait()`.

Comment: Are you a really bored programmer? :)  Like @ChrisG says `onresize` will give you what you want, but you might want to place some sort of `debounce` in there for good measure.

Comment: Updated the question with the suggested `resize`, should have added that initially, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

You have this option with css media query:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) and (orientation: landscape) { }

@media (min-height: 680px), screen and (orientation: portrait) { }
```

Comment: With these media queries, you can control the state of `landscape` and `portrait`. But as the question suggest, I am looking for a way to control what is visible and not, **during** the orientation change.

Comment: This will depend on internet speed, phone hardware, etc. In my opinion you must concentrate for optimisation overall and this will fix re-render problems, like switch orientation. An normal user will accept a 1, 1,5 seconds delay. Make an pro memory tests and you'll solve this problems.

Comment: After some further experiments, I am afraid I have to settle with this white area indeed, one optimalization I found was lowering the contrast, so the white doesn't stand out that much.

Comment: Again, use a tool to see trafic. That will show you if you loose users from    performance problems. Also, I think white color is from body, you can try to change this color if you consider will be a better UX.